# SharePoint 2007 x64 upgrade: events 3759 and 5586 when creating the SSP

Tags: 2007, upgrade

Before I start this entire process over I wanted to check in here to see if anyone had any thoughts.  I have a test environment that I'm attempting to upgrade from x86 to x64. I've completed the following steps:

- Created the x64 SharePoint server, and added it to the farm.
- Upgraded and moved databases to new x64 bit server.
- Moved Central Administration to new x64 bit server.

At this point everything is working and looks great.  The farm still contains the 32-bit front end server.  I am now trying to create a new SSP so that I can move the SSP to the new front end server.  However, when I try to create a new placeholder SSP, I get an unknown error and the following errors are thrown into the event log:

- Event 3759: Database 'my configuration database' on SQL Server instance 'alias pointing to my x64 server' is not empty and does not match current database schema.
- Event 3759: Database 'SharePoint_AdminContent_daeb26da-1d00-40b6-b7a3-17c6573dbdb1' on SQL Server instance 'alias pointing to my x64 server' is not empty and does not match current database schema.
- Event 5586: Unknown SQL Exception 262 occured. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I've googled these errors and verified that my installation account and the account I'm using to create the SSP have dbcreator roles.  I even gave the SSP Service account a sysadmin role just to see what would happen but I'm still getting the same errors.

I also verified that the versions are the same everywhere, and all sharepoint servers, sites, and the versions table in the config database have this version: 12.0.0.6421.

So, I'm a bit stumped.  I think there is a chance that I might have used my personal domain account to install the slipstream and that may be the root of all my problems, and I'll just have to start over.  But, I thought maybe someone could see something I'm overlooking.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: try to clear the config cache on all servers? Also reset IIS or if allowed reboot the servers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried clearing out the cache but no luck.  I tried rebooting the servers as well. Planning to start the process over.

Comment: are you using the current SSP db or creating brand new?Also check thishttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561042(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I've tried to create a new SSP and restore.  I should clarify that I'm getting the errors when I'm trying to create the new Web App for the SSP.

Comment: Another thing to add.  The collation on my x64 SQL server is set to: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  I'm still trying to figure out exactly what this means but I'm wondering if this could perhaps be the problem.

Comment: same thing i am thought, and link i mentioned having the fix for wrong collation.

Comment: Found out that SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS means Latin1-General, case-insensitive,
accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode
Data, while the proper (and my production server's) collation is Latin1_General, Case insensitive, Accent sensitive, Kana sensitive, width sensitive.  I'm going to try this again with matching collations and see how it goes.  Wish me luck.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE - yes it was indeed your link that sent me down the collation path.  Thanks.

Comment: all the time, that's the issue, i still in believe..

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE - the problem was the collation.  Can you change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: good to see this. i replied.

Comment: don't have enough reputation to upvote :(  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using the current SSP db or creating brand new?

Also check this

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561042(v=office.12).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561042%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Usually this is happens due to collation mis-match.